# Chrome caching renamed javascript files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching

I'm working on a website where the javascript is minified in production, but not in development, so we have a script that dynamically loads other scripts.  In order to force the browser to download new javascript versions when available, we rename the update javascript files with a version number.

The problem is that Chrome is somehow caching the functionality of the old files, even though they are no longer being requested, or exist.

The file (source below) that loads the javascript files is not versioned.

So, as an example, this morning, our combined/minified javascript file was named:

***combined-js.2.8.0.min.js***

After a deploy it was renamed to

***combined-js.2.9.0.min.js***

Looking at the Chrome debugger, you can easily see that the 2.9.0 file was requested and served, but the site functions as if the 2.8.0 file has been loaded until you clear cache.

Could this be caused by the fact that the loader file is not versioned, or something else?

The javascript used to load these files is:

```
(function loadJavascript() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open("GET","/loadjs.php", false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    // Get file paths
    if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
        fileNames = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }

    // Load JS
    var file = document.createElement('script');
    file.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    file.setAttribute("data-main","/main");
    file.setAttribute("src", "/"+fileNames.js);

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(file);

    // Load CSS
    if( typeof fileNames.css === 'string' ) {
        fileNames.css = [fileNames.css];
    }

    for (fileName in fileNames.css) {
        file = document.createElement("link");
        file.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        file.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        file.setAttribute("href", fileNames.css[fileName]);

        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(file);
    }
}());
```

Comment: It might be helpful to mention that the minified file uses a requirejs optimizer.

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab in the Chrome Dev Tools as this is requested? What does it say? Be sure to not to have disabled the cache when the Dev Tools are open.

Comment: Why do you set `fileNames = 'require.js'`, but then overwrite the variable when the AJAX request completes?

Comment: If you look at the minified JS file in the Source tab, is it the correct version?

Comment: @Barmar It's an artifact from before the CSS was being loaded.  If it couldn't find the minified file, it would load require.js.  I'll remove that, thanks for catching it

Comment: @PaulDraper The network tab indicates that the newer file was downloaded, as expected.  There is no indication of the older file.

Comment: @PMV, the Chrome Dev Tools accurately reflect the the requests made by the browser. If it says you requested the 2.9.0, but you see content from 2.8.0, it isn't a browser problem; the problem is at the server end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that adding a timestamp to the loader script fixed the problem.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var epoch = (new Date).getTime();
    document.write("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src='/load.js?t="+epoch+"'><\/script>");
</script>
```